# Given a text and an audio file, how can I highlight each word as it is spoken?

Tags: ios, swift, text-to-speech

Given a text and an audio file, how can I highlight each word as it is spoken? The text spoken in the audio file matches the given text.

Comment: you forgot to say what platform and language you're working with

Comment: sorry! I'm using Swift in iOS